# postgresql : extract(epoch function over multiple rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, epoch

I am using postgresql 8.3 (no choice in the version at this time)

My raw data is as follows:

```
ID | From  | To    | Time
01 | n/a   | open  | 06:56
01 | open  | pt1   | 07:56 
01 | pt1   | pt2   | 07:59 
01 | pt2   | pt3   | 08:36 
01 | pt3   | pt4   | 08:56  
01 | pt4   | close | 09:58
```

What I want to end up with is:

```
ID | Open_Time | Close_Time
01 | 06:56     | 09:58
```

I don't care about the time intervals between the individual parts.  I have  many ID numbers and each can have this or more are part intervals to it.  I'm fairly new to sql so I am pretty lost here.  I'm stuck on how to merge the two end and beginning rows into one row in a new view.

Comment: Do you need to care about the `from` and `to` columns? Or is it guaranteed that each series will begin with an `open` and end with a `close`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
    id ID,
    min(case rd.to when 'open' then "time" end) Open_Time,
    min(case rd.to when 'close' then "time" end) Close_Time 
from raw_data rd
group by id
```